# Chrome gives wrong result on calling toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, locale

Background: I am using JavaScript for some project.
I want to convert the input date to UTC date.
I am using the toLocaleString function provided by JavaScript to do the same.

Test Browser:
Chrome
Version : 83.0.4103.61

Below is the sample code for conversion:

```
new Date("2020/05/27 09:14:00 GMT+0900").toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "UTC", hour12: false })
```

Chrome gives the following output:

```
"5/27/2020, 24:14:00"
```

This is completely wrong.

Expected result :

```
"5/27/2020, 00:14:00"
```

Edge & Firefox browser works fine.

Is there any update of Chrome for which I should wait in order to get it resolved or should I change my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hourCycle: 'h23'` instead of `hour12: false`.
I guess in Chrome `hour12: false` means `hourCycle: 'h24'`, which causes this issue.